# Эклипс: переименовать весь проект

Tags: java, android, eclipse

У меня есть готовый проект, но его название оставляет желать лучшего, как в эклипсе возможно его переименовать, более быстрым образом, чем в ручную перебивать названия. Т.е. при установки его на телефон название должно быть таким как мне надо, а не такое как сейчас. Если кто знает по пунктам подскажите, а то я с английским не очень.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Поищи меню [refactoring](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-refactor.htm) и выбери `rename`.
2. Попробуй русифицировать Eclipse - погугли - это довольно просто.

P.S. Здесь народ не любит, когда просят сделать что-то за вас - поэтому вас и минусуют.

Answer (score 4):

С таким знанием английского противопоказано заниматься программированием. Это обычно приводит к появлению таких глупых вопросов, как ваш.

Правой кнопкой мыши на проект, нажать Rename, ввести новое имя, нажать ОК.  
Или можно при помощи горячей клавиши F2